# Verify if Spacebars HTML syntax is correct

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, blaze

I have a project using a Meteor + Blaze + Spacebars stack.

Whenever I have an error inside one of the HTML files (which are processed with Spacebars), the html is not loaded on the client. This is fine, except the only error I get from this is something like `Uncaught Error: No such template: <template-name>`.

Is there a way to verify which HTML files fail to compile and maybe get some specific errors?

Comment: Run the [Spacebars compiler](https://github.com/meteor/blaze/tree/master/packages/spacebars-compiler) against the templates ahead of time. You will then know if they compile and you should get error messages.

Comment: The server console (where you ran `meteor`) should tell you more than that. Have you already checked that?

Comment: @ChristianFritz when running `meteor` I don't get any errors. The only output is the usual started messages with the final being `=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/`. But the browser console has the `No such template` error. Which disappears after fixing the HTML and the page renders properly.

Comment: @user1538301 The spacebars compiler runs without errors

Comment: Then I don't think you actually do have an error in your HTML. Which URL are you opening and can you show the route definition for that URL?

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught Error: No such template:

I think you have no html errors, but you didn't imported your template. 
Just to remind:

1. import child templates **before** parent templates;
2. import `html` template file before related `.js` file
3. check if you are using correct include syntax and template name.

example:

```
import './partsTemplates/leftCol.html';
import './partsTemplates/leftCol.js';

import './pageTemplates/dashboard/dashboard.html';
import './pageTemplates/dashboard/dashboard.js'
```

Here, the template `dashboard` uses template `leftCol`.
`leftCol` is a **template** name (`<template name="leftCol">`), not a file name.

```
{{>leftCol}}
```